# How do I get an empty value to be an empty value instead of a hash?

Tags: perl

I'm having trouble acquiring the value of middle name from my XML file.

This is my XML file:

```
<PERSON>
<ID>1</ID>
<FIRSTNAME>JOHN</FIRSTNAME>
<MIDDLENAME></MIDDLENAME>
<LASTNAME>SMITH</LASTNAME>
</PERSON>
```

This is how I access my XML file:

```
// [...]
use XML::Simple;

my $file = shift;

open FILE,"$file" or die $!;
my @rawFile = <FILE>;
close (FILE);

my $xml = new XML::Simple;

my $data = $xml->XMLin("@rawFile");

my $place = "PERSON"
my $field = "MIDDLENAME"
my $value = $data->{$place}->{$self->{field}};

if (defined $value)
{
     print "Value is $value"
     print Dumper($data->{$place}); 
}
```

This is the output:

```
Value is [HASH(0x8ed6e28)]
$VAR1 = {
    'ID' => '1',
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'JOHN',
    'MIDDLENAME' => {},
    'LASTNAME' => 'SMITH',
    'PHONE' => '5551234'
}
```

How do I access my middle name $value so that it returns `""` (an empty string) instead of `[HASH(0x8ed6e28)]`?

Note that if `$field="FIRSTNAME"` then the proper value of `"John"` is returned in `$value`.

Comment: It turns out that the only line I need to change was:      my $data = $xml->XMLin("@rawIsh", SuppressEmpty => '');   # but my reputation is too low to answer my own question :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML::Simple is one of the easiest parsers to use. ;D As Adron mentioned [SuppressEmpty](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aSimple#SuppressEmpty-1-undef-in-out---handy) controls how to handle values.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $raw_file;

while(<>)
{
    $raw_file .= $_;
}

print Dumper( XMLin( $raw_file, SuppressEmpty => '' ) ); 

exit;
```

This code snippet is producing the following output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ID' => '1',
          'MIDDLENAME' => '',
          'LASTNAME' => 'SMITH',
          'FIRSTNAME' => 'JOHN'
        };
```

Answer (score 4):

XML::Simple is the hardest XML parser to use. `ForceContent => 1` would do the trick, although it would change your structure a bit.

Personally, I use XML::LibXML.

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($qfn);

my %person;
for my $node ($doc->findnodes('/PERSON/*')) {
   $person{ $node->nodeName() } = $node->textContent();
}
```